# Java VirtualVm connection attempt produces "Java(TM) platform SE has stopped working" error

Tags: java, windows, profiling

When I'm trying to open connections to some applications...

[image]

`VisualVm` service sometimes provides me an error below:

[image]

This error is reproduced not for the all jar connections, and was discovered under the Windows OS. My team-mates that used Linux-based OS with the same jar applications, were not affected by such kind of problems.

My questions is **how to handle the exact failure cause, while "VisualVm" application does not provide any additional information about it by default**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't found an exhaustive answer to this question, so giving my solution. Hope it might be useful for someone in a future

**First of all, you need to find a way to analyze the internal cause of the `VisualVm` crash. To do this, you just need to add the console logging option.**

Open the configuration file:

`% JAVA_HOME%/lib/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf` and append

`-J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea` keys to the `visualvm_default_options`

When you run the `VisualVm` application from the console and repeat the failed action, you'll get a full stack trace.

In my particular case, the problem was dealing with the forbidden connection to the `VirtualBox` host (`VisualVm` was started in non-administrator mode)

This problem can be solved either (**my particular case**) by properly configuring the network, or by running `VisualVm` in the administrative mode (**in general case it might help**).

But anyway I strongly recommend you to handle the exact reason of `VisualVm` failure